# DioException (DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.)

Tags: rest, http, request, status

[image]

Dio Exception (Dio Exception [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.)

The error message you provided, "Dio Exception [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400," suggests that an HTTP request made using the Dio library encountered an error. Let's break down the components of this error message:

1. **`Dio Exception`**: Dio is a popular HTTP client library used in various programming languages, including Dart (for Flutter). **`Dio Exception`** is an exception class provided by the Dio library to handle errors related to network requests.
2. **`[bad response]`**: This part of the error message indicates that the HTTP request did not receive a successful response from the server. Instead, it received a response that is considered "bad" or erroneous.
3. **`The request returned an invalid status code of 400`**: This portion of the error message specifies the specific issue with the response. In this case, the server responded with a status code of 400. The HTTP status code 400 is known as the "Bad Request" status code. It indicates that the server could not process the request due to a client error.
4. A status code of 400 is often returned when the server cannot understand or process the request sent by the client. It could occur due to various reasons, such as missing or incorrect parameters, malformed request data, or authentication issues.